# IJSRuntime issue on calling actions

Tags: blazor, blazor-jsruntime

I get an error of

> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Rendering.WebAssemblyRenderer[100]
> Unhandled exception rendering component: Could not find
> 'encryptMessage' ('encryptMessage' was undefined).
>
> Error: Could not find 'encryptMessage' ('encryptMessage' was
> undefined).

When I run my blazor application. This is the script in the index.html

```
<script>
    
    ... OTHER FUNCTIONS

    function encryptMessage(message, key) {
        console.log("HERE")
        
    }
</script>
```

and this is in my component cs

```
using Microsoft.JSInterop;

[Inject] IJSRuntime? mJsRunTime { get; set; }

private async Task Login()
{

    await mJsRunTime!.InvokeVoidAsync("encryptMessage", $@"{username}:{password}", "usernamwe");

}
```

Comment: It kinda looks all in order...
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/javascript-interoperability/call-javascript-from-dotnet?view=aspnetcore-6.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problems are elsewhere.

Clean Blazor WASM Project.

My Index.html

```cs
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
    <title>BlazorApp1</title>
    <base href="/" />
    <link href="css/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="css/app.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="favicon.png" />
    <link href="BlazorApp1.styles.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>

<body>
    <div id="app">
        <svg class="loading-progress">
            <circle r="40%" cx="50%" cy="50%" />
            <circle r="40%" cx="50%" cy="50%" />
        </svg>
        <div class="loading-progress-text"></div>
    </div>

    <div id="blazor-error-ui">
        An unhandled error has occurred.
        <a href="" class="reload">Reload</a>
        <a class="dismiss"></a>
    </div>
    <script src="_framework/blazor.webassembly.js"></script>
    <script>
        function encryptMessage(message, key) {
            console.log("HERE")
        }
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Test Page:

```
@page "/"
@inject IJSRuntime js

<PageTitle>Index</PageTitle>

<h1>Hello, world!</h1>

Welcome to your new app.

<button class="btn btn-primary" @onclick=LogIn>Log In</button>

@code{
    private string username = string.Empty;
    private string password = string.Empty;

    private async Task LogIn()
    {
        await js.InvokeVoidAsync("encryptMessage", $@"{username}:{password}", "usernamwe");
    }
}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: I read somewhere on GitHub and it's the only thing I did and it worked! Thank you though!

Comment: [Polite]  You also [inadvertently and unknowingly] did something else.  Anyway, main thing is a result.

Comment: No Sir. The only thing I did was really put the that script at the end. I will look for it. I closed my tabs after making it work and moved on. lemme find it.

Comment: Don't worry, it wasn't an accusation.  Fixed so who cares.  :-)

Comment: Couldn't find it anymore. Sorry. But I really saw that post in Github and just followed it. Maybe I can replicate it by placing this script at the top.

Comment: Wow! I guess you're right. even when I changed the placement, it still is working fine. Hmmm. Well I'll remove my "answer" post then. Thank you for pointing it out.

Comment: There's lots of voodoo out there!